# Adding content to a specific view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have views in a dropdown which hold my content lists, the issue is I cannot add specific content to a specific view.

I have 2 views; Current affairs and Education, I want to add content to a specific view; lets say to the Discussions view but when I add content it is added to both my views here are snips
[image]

I decide to add "PK Chishala Bana Mulenga" and "Child Labour, How can we alleviate it?" but I find them in both the Current Affairs view and Education view anyone who knows how I can solve this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A View is basically a query builder. You need to provide it with a filter that includes the content you want to show, and excludes the content you don't want to show.

There are many different different ways to solve it, here are a few of the common ones:

- Use different content types for the different types of content, and filter by "Content type" in the Views
- Add a Vocabulary, "Post Type" or something, with "Current Affairs" & "Education" as terms; attach a term reference field for that vocab to the content type, filter on that instead in the Views
- Add a boolean/text/numeric/whatever field to the content type, set that to a value on a node-by-node basis, use that to filter the Views.

Comment: and when you filter, make sure the **for** is NOT set to `All Displays`, rather set it to `This page (override)` or `This block (override)`. [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1S4D2.jpg), so it only affects this specific view display.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options open to you, here are 2:

1. Put taxonomy terms on your content and filter the view for specific taxonomy terms.  This is the more automatic version
2. Use an [entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) for each view, which requires much more manual input, but gives you the ability to explicitly choose the order in which articles appear.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vocabulary under admin/structure/taxonomy & add terms like current affairs and education.Now create a field in your content type with term reference and choose your vocabulary now when add content choose any of the term from the field like education or current affairs.

Now create views and in filter criteria choose has taxonomy term & choose your vocabulary & select either of the term education or current affairs.

Now create another page view for the same view with different path and select the remaining term. That's how the content will not get repeated in both views

Comment: This is good if the current affairs and education belong to the same content type. If they do not, might as well filter by content type.